# SriRangam Ranganathaswamy - the kula devata or kula deivam of Sri Ram?

Tags: ramayana

There are claims that Lord Ranganathaswamy of Srirangam in Tamilnadu is the kula deivam or kul devata of Lord Rama.

Is there any truth to it?